# How to flatten a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

Is there a native function to flatten a nested dictionary to an output dictionary where keys and values are in this format:

```
_dict2 = {
  'this.is.an.example': 2,
  'this.is.another.value': 4,
  'this.example.too': 3,
  'example': 'fish'
}
```

Assuming the dictionary will have several different value types, how should I go about iterating the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to traverse the dictionary, building the current key and accumulating the flat dictionary. For example:

```
def flatten(current, key, result):
    if isinstance(current, dict):
        for k in current:
            new_key = "{0}.{1}".format(key, k) if len(key) > 0 else k
            flatten(current[k], new_key, result)
    else:
        result[key] = current
    return result

result = flatten(my_dict, '', {})
```

Using it:

```
print(flatten(_dict1, '', {}))

{'this.example.too': 3, 'example': 'fish', 'this.is.another.value': 4, 'this.is.an.example': 2}
```

Comment: There's no need to call the `keys` method when iterating over a dictionary.

Comment: i see, "flatten" would have been a better term to describe it. thank you for the example. >learning

Comment: Also `type(current) is dict` could be replaced with `isinstance(current, dict)` to make the code a bit more general purpose making it work with OrderedDict as well.