# flatten nested dict values in a list in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, vimeo-api

I've got this data structure coming from Vimeo API

```
{'duration': 720, 
'language': 'sv',
'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsale/incidentbyabank',
'name': 'INCIDENT BY A BANK',
'user': {
    'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsales',
    'location': 'Warsaw, Poland',
    'name': 'New Europe Film Sales'
    }
}
```

I want to transofrm in

```
[720, "sv", "http..", "incident.." "http..", "Warsaw", "New Europe.."]
```

to load it in a Google spreadsheet. I also need to maintain consistence values order.

PS. I see similar questions but answers are not in Python 3

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `csv` module with a header? The order won't matter if you use a header.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but i want Google spreadsheet to update dinamically adding new rows every day. I don't think CSV is a solution

Comment: What module are you using to update the google spreadsheets? Maybe you can download it to a local copy, edit that one with `csv`, and then upload back to google?

Comment: I'm using gspread

Comment: There's a `import_csv` function you can use. https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Client.import_csv

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to create a CSV file like you've described out of your data.

First, we should use a header row for your file, so the order doesn't matter, only dict keys do:

```
import csv

# This defines the order they'll show up in final file
fieldnames = [
    'name', 'link', 'duration', 'language',
    'user_name', 'user_link', 'user_location',
]

# Open the file with Python
with open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as my_file:

    # Attach a CSV writer to the file with the desired fieldnames
    writer = csv.DictWriter(my_file, fieldnames)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writeheader()
```

Notice the `DictWriter`, this will allow us to write dicts based on their keys instead of the order (dicts are unordered pre-3.6). The above code will end up with a file like this:

```
name;link;duration;language;user_name;user_link;user_location
```

Which we can then add rows to, but let's convert your data first, so the keys match the above field names:

```
data = {
    'duration': 720, 
    'language': 'sv',
    'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsale/incidentbyabank',
    'name': 'INCIDENT BY A BANK',
    'user': {
        'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsales',
        'location': 'Warsaw, Poland',
        'name': 'New Europe Film Sales'
    }
}

for key, value in data['user'].items():
    data['user_{}'.format(key)] = value
del data['user']
```

This ends up with the `data` dictionary like this:

```
data = {
    'duration': 720, 
    'language': 'sv',
    'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsale/incidentbyabank',
    'name': 'INCIDENT BY A BANK',
    'user_link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsales',
    'user_location': 'Warsaw, Poland',
    'user_name': 'New Europe Film Sales',
}
```

We can now simply insert this as a whole row to the CSV writer, and everything else is done automatically:

```
# Using the same writer from above, insert the data from above
writer.writerow(data)
```

That's it, now just import this into your Google spreadsheets :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution using recursion:

```
dictionary = {
    'duration': 720, 
    'language': 'sv',
    'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsale/incidentbyabank',
    'name': 'INCIDENT BY A BANK',
    'user': {
        'link': 'https://vimeo.com/neweuropefilmsales',
        'location': 'Warsaw, Poland',
        'name': 'New Europe Film Sales'
    }
}


def flatten(current: dict, result: list=[]):
    if isinstance(current, dict):
        for key in current:
            flatten(current[key], result)
    else:
        result.append(current)

    return result


result = flatten(dictionary)
print(result)
```

*Explanation:* We call `flatten()` until we reach a value of the dictionary, that is not a dictionary itself (`if isinstance(current, dict):`). If we reach this value, we append it to our `result list`. It will work for any number of nested dictionaries.

See: [How would I flatten a nested dictionary in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448543/how-would-i-flatten-a-nested-dictionary-in-python-3)
*I used the same solution, but I've changed the `result` collection to be a list.*

Comment: Thanks the flatten function at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448543/how-would-i-flatten-a-nested-dictionary-in-python-3?answertab=votes#tab-top is working also in a for loop, while yours add the previous elements for each iteration

Comment: No, it's different to that. This method produces a list, and the one you linked to produces a dict. They are both almost identical recursive solutions.